# Perl -- DBI selectall_arrayref when querying getting Not Hash Reference

Tags: sql-server, perl, dbi

I am very new to perl (but from a c# background) and I am trying to move some scripts to a windows box. 
Due to some modules not working easily with windows I have changed the way it connects to the DB.
I have an sqlserver DB and I had a loop reading each row in a table, and then within this loop another query was sent to select different info. 
I was the error where two statements can't be executed at once within the same connection.
As my connection object is global I couldn't see an easy way round this, so decided to store the first set of data in an array using:

```
my $query = shift;
    my $aryref = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($query) || die "Could not select to array\n";
    return($aryref);
```

(this is in a module file that is called)

I then do a foreach loop (where  @$s_study is the $aryref returned above)

```
  foreach my $r_study ( @$s_study ) {
    ~~~             
    my $surveyId=$r_study->{surveyid};  <-------error this line
 ~~~~               
        };
```

When I run this I get an error "Not a hash reference". I don't understand?! 
Can anyone help!

Bex

Answer (score 11):

You need to provide the `{ Slice => {} }` parameter to [`selectall_arrayref`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#selectall_arrayref) if you want each row to be stored as a hash:

```
my $aryref = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($query, { Slice => {} });
```

By default, it returns a reference to an array containing a reference to an array for each row of data fetched.

Comment: I tried this the first time but removed it as I thought this was causing the error.. I think benzebuth below may have it?

Answer (score 2):

`$r_study->{surveyid}` is a hashref

`$r_study->[0]` is an arrayref

this is your error.
You should use the second one

Comment: Ah.. is there anyway I can query the columns by name? I need the "data set" offline ...

Comment: you should be able to call `selectall_hashref` if you want a hashref.  Check out the full docs here:  http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#selectall_hashref

Comment: selectall_hashref returns a hash ref of hash refs. Bex wants an array ref of hash refs. So selectall_arrayref is the right way to go - but with the addition of { Slice => {} }.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem with a method, then a good first step is to read the documentation for that method. Here's a link to the documentation for [selectall_arrayref](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#selectall_arrayref). It says:

> This utility method combines
>   "prepare", "execute" and
>   "fetchall_arrayref" into a single
>   call. It returns a reference to an
>   array containing a reference to an
>   array (or hash, see below) for each
>   row of data fetched.

So the default behaviour is to return a reference to an array which contains an **array reference** for each row. That explains your error. You're getting an array reference and you're trying to treat it as a hash reference. I'm not sure that the error could be much clearer.

There is, however, that interesting bit where it says "or hash, see below". Reading on, we find:

> You may often want to fetch an array
>   of rows where each row is stored as a
>   hash. That can be done simple using:
>
> ```
> my $emps = $dbh->selectall_arrayref(
>     "SELECT ename FROM emp ORDER BY ename",
>     { Slice => {} }
> );
> foreach my $emp ( @$emps ) {
>     print "Employee: $emp->{ename}\n";
> }
> ```

So you have two options. Either switch your code to use an array ref rather than a hash ref. Or add the "{ Slice => {} }" option to the call, which will return a hash ref.

The documentation is clear. It's well worth reading it.

Comment: Davorg.. that is the exact article I was reading.. I have done as your second example shows and that's when I am getting the error "Not Hash Reference". It's the whole concept of "hashes" that I don't really understand.. nor why the example isn't working for me! 
Ps.. I did have the slice in it to start.. but removed it as found conflicting documentation.. either way didn't work!

Comment: Ok. I suspect that we might be going in completely the wrong direction here. I assume that the code was working (with Slice => {}) before you moved the application to Windows. So I wonder if the problem is that your Windows box has an older version of DBI which doesn't support that syntax. Can you try running "perl -MDBI -le'print $DBI::VERSION'" on both of the systems to report what versions of DBI you have installed. You might need to update the version of DBI on your Windows system.

Comment: I've just checked the changelog (http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/Changes) and the Slice => {} syntax was added in DBI version 1.20 which was released in 2001. I really hope you're not using a version that is that old :-)

Comment: in the file it says I am running v 1.6.15 (im not sure where you mean run the other bit?) - this method wasn't on the old box, it was using DBD::sybase to connect to the db, but I couldn't get the client libraries, so I changed it to using straight DBI with a DSN to connect to Sql server, but I have nested queries and I was getting the error:Connection is busy with results for another hstmt (SQL-HY000) .... tried adding the odbc_cursortype => 2  but it didn't fix it, that;s why I changed it to try using an array. I don't mind which error can be fixed, but so far I'm stumped with both!

Answer (score 0):

When you encounter something like "Not a hash reference" or "Not an array reference" or similar you can always take Data::Dumper to just dump out your variable and you will quickly see what data you are dealing with: arrays of arrayrefs, hashes of something etc.
And concerning reading the data, this `{ Slice => {} }` is most valuable addition.